# Image elements do not have explicit width and height in Picture

Tags: html, image, media-queries, google-pagespeed

PageSpeed Insights warning me:

> Set an explicit width and height on image elements to reduce layout
> shifts and improve CLS.

But how I can fix it if I use **Picture** tag like this:

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/150.webp" media="(max-width: 768px)" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/150.png x1, https://via.placeholder.com/300.png x2" media="(max-width: 768px)" type="image/png">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/500.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/500.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500.png">
</picture>
```

I don't need in mobile version image tag with **width** and **height** 500px. I want responsive image.

Of course i can set attributes  **width** and **height** in image tag with value 500 and then use **!import** with **@media** in css, but i think it's just invalid rule.

How i can avoid this warning or fix it if it possible?

Comment: I have the exact same question and I haven't found a reasonable answer to this. We would need to be able to add "width" and "height" attributes to the source element

Comment: Have you found solution for that?

Comment: @dgb23 You can add width and height attributes to source element. Morden browsers support this and this is also in the current HTML 5 spec.

Answer (score 3):

This Pagespeed Insights message is misleading, you are NOT required to set the width + height of your images using the HTML attributes, you can also use CSS.

To be compliant with the rule in a `<picture>` you can either:

- Set a `width` + `height` in CSS: `.your-image { width: 200px; height: 150px; }`
- Set a `width` + `aspect-ratio` in CSS: `.your-image { width: 100%; aspect-ratio: 16 / 10; }`
- Set a `height` + `aspect-ratio` in CSS: `.your-image { height: 300px; aspect-ratio: 16 / 10; }`

This CSS needs to be inlined or in a non-async/deffered file.

The `width` can be declared as percent in the CSS.

Source: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13098